# Combine plots in R

Tags: r, plot, interaction, gridextra

I have several plots that I want to combine them together and add a title to the combined plot, but somehow I cannot combine them using R. (using RStudio)

1. Combine two residual plots plotted by using `plot(resid(lme))` where lme is a linear mixed model.
2. Combine two interaction plots plotted by using `interaction.plot(x1,x2,y)` where x1 and x2 are the two independent variables, and y is the dependent variable.

I tried to store the plots as variables and use `grid.arrange`, but they cannot be stored into  a variable (just produce the plot in the plot area).

i.e.

```
> int1 <- interaction.plot(data_pos_10$Day,data_pos_10$Drug,data_pos_10$Tumor.Volume,
+                  xlab="Day",ylab="Tumor Volume",main="Interaction Plot Batch 10",
+                  legend=F,
+                  col=c("red","red","green","black","blue"),
+                  lwd=2,
+                  lty=c(1,2,3,4,5))
> int1
NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you do your plotting code, run `par(mcol=c(2,1))` to stack them vertically or `par(mcol=c(1,2))` to stack them horizontally.

Comment: Yes, it works. But how do I add a title to the combined plot? Thanks!

Comment: Try `?mtext` for the title.

Comment: I think I got it, just run 'title("...")' after that.