# CCF - general problems

Tags: r, cross-correlation

I am working on my bachelor thesis, where I want to look into the lagged cross-correlation of a timeseries of search query volumes (=x) to the price of bitcoin (=y).

I have already created several ccf-plots using the "ccf"-function in R .

See picture:
[image: (see pictures)]

I saw in the description of R's [acf-function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/acf.html) that ccf only works with one y and one x series. I was wondering if someone knows a way to put several of those plots into one, especially since I can categorize positively correlated and negatively correlated ones.

Further I was wondering, the dashed-blue line representing the confidence value, but at what level? 0.05? 0.01?

Answer (score 0):

These are two questions in one.

**1. question: combine plots**
This question has been asked before. Please look it up:

- [Combining plots created by R base, lattice, and ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50012553/combining-plots-created-by-r-base-lattice-and-ggplot2)
- [Combine plots in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22309739/combine-plots-in-r)

**2. question: confidence intervals in ccf-plot:**
The plot gives you the confidence intervals. The manual advises caution with these even though it uses `ci.type = "white"` is default setting. This default bluntly adds some confidence based on the quantiles of a standard normal distribution. It does not take the statistical properties of your data into account. In my opinion it is altogether useless. The manual recommends `ci.type = "ma"`. But that will only work for autocorrelations. If you try using it with cross-correlations, you will get a warning saying "can use ci.type=‘ma’ only if first lag is 0". When doing autocorrelations the function shifts the sequences from -k to +k and will allow the first lag to be zero. ccf does not.

**Further support**

I hope it is not against the code of conduct to offer further support.

The ccf function has some pecularities that aren't well explained in the manual. Since I had trouble with ccf myself I wrote it all [down here for everybody](https://medium.com/@jan.seifert/the-r-cross-correlation-function-f5f426006425?source=friends_link&sk=60e3a85df26d2eebd0c47ab84c3407c0).

Because I wanted meaningful confidence intervals I developed [an improved version of 'ccf' (link to repository in case anyone is interested)](https://github.com/SigurdJanson/ccf21) myself. It offers confidence intervals. The ccf-object by the new function is compatible with the output by `stats::ccf()` but contains more information. Additional functions make it more useful.